# Inverse of square root of a PSD (positive semi-definite) matrix

Tags: r

Suppose I have a  positive semi-definite matrix `S` and I would like to get the inverse of square root of this matrix, that is `S^(-1/2)`.

May I do like this?

```
ei <- eigen(S)
V <- ei$vectors
res <- V %*% diag(1 / sqrt(ei$values)) %*% t(V)
```

Is `res` equal to `S^(-1/2)`?

I just do `inverse of square root` for eigenvalue of `S`, is this correct?

I know that: if one wants to get `S^(1/2)`, then `res <- V %*% diag(sqrt(ei$values)) %*% t(V)`, which is `res = S^(1/2)`.

How about for `S^(-1/2)`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  We can easily take an example S and check that S times res times res is the identity matrix:

```
set.seed(123)
S <- crossprod(matrix(rnorm(9), 3))

ei <- eigen(S)
V <- ei$vectors
res <- V %*% diag(1 / sqrt(ei$values)) %*% t(V)

S %*% res %*% res
##             [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
## [1,]  1.0000e+00 -2.3731e-15 -1.6653e-16
## [2,]  3.3346e-15  1.0000e+00 -6.6613e-16
## [3,] -1.0235e-16  8.3267e-16  1.0000e+00
```

Also note that S and res commute, i.e. `all.equal(S %*% res, res %*% S)` is TRUE, so the 3 factors in the last line of code could have been written in any order.

Answer (score 1):

If, as per the OP's enquiry, the input matrix is positive semi-definite (and not positive definite), its eigenvalues will not all be positive, and the method given in the answer above will fail, since

```
diag(1 / sqrt(ei$values))
```

will not be a finite matrix.